# Excepciones, memoria dinámica y destructores

Tags: c++

Entiendo que si uno implementa una *ADT* esta debería comportarse como los tipos nativos y ser sus instancias destruidas al terminar su vida útil, pero...

¿Qué pasa si el usuario de la clase declara un `raw pointer` para usar `new` con un tipo de esa *ADT*?

En principio el destructor será invocado, a menos que se lance una excepción y esa memoria que se perdió. ¿Cómo puedo evitarlo?

Seguidamente incluyo un ejemplo que ilustra el problema:

```
/*
    Implementación "cutre" de una clase para números 
    complejos, el objetivo es que los objetos de esta
    clase puedan usarse como los tipos nativos, lo que 
    se demuestra problemático al usar un raw pointer para
    almacenar un tipo complejo en el heap.

    Code by José Antonio Martínez Escobedo

*/

#include<iostream>
#include<exception>

class Complex {
public:

    Complex(double real = 0, double img = 0) : r(r), i(i){}

    ~Complex()  // el destructor debería ser invocado dos veces...
    {
        std::cout << "Objeto destruido" << std::endl;
    }

private:

    double r, i;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Complex z1;
        Complex* z2 = new Complex{ 6,1 };
        throw (std::exception{ "Trouble" });
        delete z2;  //memory leak!
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
    std::cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para evitar ese problema que describes se inventaron los ¡punteros inteligentes!

Los punteros inteligentes residen en la cabecera [`<memory>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) y dispones del puntero único ([`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) el puntero compartido ([`std::shared_ptr`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) y el puntero débil ([`std::weak_ptr`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)), deberás decidir cuál se ajusta a tus necesidades.

---

Por lo que deduzco de tu código, el puntero único es lo que en tu caso necesitas:

```
using Complex_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Complex>;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Complex z1;
        Complex_ptr z2 = std::make_unique<Complex>(6,1);
        throw std::logic_error("Trouble");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Al lanzarse una excepción, el estándar de C++ garantiza que se llamarán los destructores de los objetos del ámbito en que la excepción fue lanzada, así pues `z2` es destruido al salir del bloque `try`.

Si te das cuenta, también he eliminado la instrucción `delete z2;` ya que el borrado del objeto se hace automáticamente al abandonar el ámbito.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

El constructor de `Complex` inicializa mal las variables miembro, revísalo:

```
Complex(double real = 0, double img = 0) : r(real), i(img){}
//                                           ~~~~     ~~~
```

No se pueden construir excepciones con inicialización de agregado, por otro lado, es mejor lanzar una excepción específica que una genérica, por eso he cambiado tu excepción a esto:

```
throw std::logic_error("Trouble");
```

Supongo que tu clase `Complex` es sólo un ejemplo, pero ten en cuenta que no te hace falta desarrollarla porque C++ dispone de una clase [`std::complex`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tus respuestas, ¿pero los smart pointers no son a partir de C++11? Tengo la intención de usar C++11 y es en verdad lo que estoy estudiando, pero ¿Qué hago si he de lidiar con una aplicación anterior a C++11?

Comment: @JoséAntonioMartínezEscobedo estás en lo cierto, los punteros inteligentes son de C++11 o superior. Si estás en versiones anteriores puedes usar el (deprecado) `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: Bien esto responde la pregunta, estoy muy agradecido, tambien he oido que en la librería boost una aproximación decente a los punteros inteligentes...espero usar sólo C++11 o superior, pero como estudiante de Física me va a tocar interactuar incluso con aplicaciones en FORTRAN, pero bueno, no sirve de nada adelantar el dolor de cabeza, y por ahora aprender bien el C++ moderno, muchas gracias por tu atención ^_^

Comment: @JoséAntonioMartinezEscobedo, Una pequeña contribución a la excelente respuesta: Los punteros inteligentes *podrían* estar presentes en compiladores anteriores a C++11 mediante la implementación del TR1 ([Technical Report 1] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1)), y residir en el espacio de nombres `std::tr1`.  No sé quién esté usando tales compiladores, pero ya que mencionas que vas a interactuar con FORTRAN (yo lo llevé en...1985) por si acaso.  Por supuesto, la biblioteca/librería Boost también los tiene, ya que se originaron ahí.